# outofmemory exception when using pdfreader itext version 5.5.0

Tags: java, memory, itext, out-of-memory, heap-memory

Facing a strange issue while reading a pdf using pdfreader.(itext)

```
PdfReader reader = PdfReader(bytearray).
```

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
> at java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Arrays.java:3236)    at
> java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.grow(ByteArrayOutputStream.java:118)    at
> java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.ensureCapacity(ByteArrayOutputStream.java:93)
> at
> java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.write(ByteArrayOutputStream.java:153)
> at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfReader.FlateDecode(PdfReader.java:2071)
> at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfReader.FlateDecode(PdfReader.java:1926)
> at
> com.itextpdf.text.pdf.FilterHandlers$Filter_FLATEDECODE.decode(FilterHandlers.java:108)
> at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfReader.decodeBytes(PdfReader.java:2476)
> at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfReader.decodeBytes(PdfReader.java:2424)
> at
> com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfReader.getStreamBytes(PdfReader.java:2489)
> at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfReader.readObjStm(PdfReader.java:1430)
> at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfReader.readDocObj(PdfReader.java:1365)
> at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfReader.readPdf(PdfReader.java:672)  at
> com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfReader.(PdfReader.java:181)    at
> com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfReader.(PdfReader.java:250)    at
> com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfReader.(PdfReader.java:240)

pdf is about 20 megabytes. strange thing is, this worked in 2020,in my old pc. i changed my pc few months back. suddenly this error pops up. any thoughts ? i tried this in intellij, no luck.intellij config looks like this. intellij 2019.3.5 community edition

```
> -Xms512m
> -Xmx820m
> -XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=1024m
> -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC
> -XX:SoftRefLRUPolicyMSPerMB=50
> -ea
> -XX:CICompilerCount=2
> -Dsun.io.useCanonPrefixCache=false
> -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true
> -Djdk.http.auth.tunneling.disabledSchemes=""
> -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError
> -XX:-OmitStackTraceInFastThrow
> -Djdk.attach.allowAttachSelf=true
> -Dkotlinx.coroutines.debug=off
> -Djdk.module.illegalAccess.silent=true
```

any thoughts ? i am using a windows 10, 64 bit system- java 8

Comment: It’s clear from the stack trace that PdfReader is making a copy of your byte array, effectively doubling (or more likely tripling) the memory usage.  Consider passing something [other than a byte array](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/com.itextpdf/itextpdf/5.5.1/com/itextpdf/text/pdf/PdfReader.html#constructor_summary) to the PdfReader constructor.

Comment: Try `-Xmx1500m` and why do you use such a huge code cache size? You can easily half that (or even more). to get  an impression start jconsole and select code cache...

Comment: @Lonzak reducing xmx  worked, thanks lonzak

Comment: @Parameswar Ok I added it as an answer so that you can accept it...

Comment: @VGR *"It’s clear from the stack trace that PdfReader is making a copy of your byte array"* - that is not exactly clear. The stack trace talks about a single object stream inside the pdf being decompressed. But indeed, depending on whether or not partial mode is requested in the constructor, the whole file may be parsed into an object model of the pdf.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To convert my comment into an answer since the OP said it helped solve the problem:

Increase the heap with `-Xmx1500m` (or even to `-Xmx2048m`).

One side note: Why do you use such a huge code cache size? You can easily half that `-XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=512m` (or even more `-XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=256m`). To get an impression start on what you really need you can use jconsole and select `code cache` section.